# SSRS Report Column Name Is not changing

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working on SSRS Reports 2005. In the reports there are some columns like First Name, Last Name. I am changing there columns name to FirstName, LastName. After doing this while I am showing the preview of the report old field are reflected instead of new field. When i am view the XML of the report, I am able to view my changes in XML. So why i am not be able to view my changes in preview. Is any thing caching issue? how can i solve this issue. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you let us know of Justin's answer helped you?

Comment: sorry.. I had tried Justin's answer. But my changes did not reflect :(

Answer (score 1):

SSRS has serious caching tendencies. In the Preview tab, you should right click your report and hit "Refresh". You may have to do that each time you change the report.